# inline images MDX Gatsby

Tags: gatsby-image, gatsby-remark-image

I'm trying to implement inline images with mdx files.

But I can't make it happen, no image is loaded.

After a bit of reading [some solutions here](https://gatsby-personal-starter-blog.netlify.app/blog/awesome-images/), they suggest to add `gatsby-remark-images` also in the plugins array in options.plugins as in

```js
`gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-remark-images`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
          },
        ],
        plugins: [`gatsby-remark-images`],
      },
    },
```

in my mdx file `![test image]('./myFirstPost/images/colorcloud.jpg')`

It didn't work for me though.
Anybody can help me with some guidance ?

Cheers

Comment: seems like the latest version of gatsby-plugin-mdx doesn't allow plugins in that field, I got this error: `Invalid plugin options for "gatsby-plugin-mdx":

- "plugins" must contain 0 items`

Answer (score 0):

Yes turned out after spending half a morning on the matter that there's no needs of quotes in the md link to the img